# Help, identifying mega blok kit - bag label X1033A and X1031A

Tags: set-identification, clone-brands

I need help identifying this kit, thanks

One bag is labeled X1033A and X1031A
I tried looking at Halo kits

[image: bag label X1033A and X1031A]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think these parts are from:

Mega Bloks Halo-Covenant Wraith Ambush

[image]